# Flutter how to sort a Firestore collection based on index of another collection

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-listview

I have a FireStore collection named "products" and in there I have documents consisting of product data such as name, price, and category. It follows the structure like this

```
    {
     "name": "Milk Shake Strawberry",
     "price": "250",
     "category": "Drinks",
     "categoryID:1234
   },
   {
     "name": "Swiss Roll",
     "price": "150",
     "category": "Cake",
     "categoryID":1235
   }
```

I map all the product data to **ProductItemData** using the following code,

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>?>? productItemsData = snapshots.data?.docs
                              .map((e) => e.data() as Map<String, dynamic>?)
                              .toList();
```

Using forEach, I collect the List of Category names into this

```
List<String> _tabs = [];

        for (var doc in productItemsData!) {
                            Map<String, dynamic> data =
                                doc as Map<String, dynamic>;
                            if (!_tabs.contains(data["category"])) {
                              _tabs.add(data["category"]);
                            }
                          }
```

So I can show the data(product items) in a TabBar View. With all the products under the relevant category name.

To get the relevant product items I use the following code to get Widgets that show product data.

```
    List<Widget> _list = [];
for (int i = 0; i < productItemsData!.length; i++) {
  if(productItemsData![i]!["category"] == category) {
    _list.add(_buildCustomProductTile(context, productItemsData![i]));
  }
} return list;
```

This far my requirement is 100% working as expected. But now I want to reorder the categories according to an index, and when the UI shows the products I want them to be in that order.

To store the categories and categoryID's I have a different collection, and it goes similar to this,

```
    {
     "index": "0",
     "categoryName": "Drinks",
     "categoryID:1234
   },
   {
     "index": "1",
     "categoryName": "Cake",
     "categoryID":1235
   }
```

By using ReorderableListView I reorder the categories by changing the index in **onReorder** function.

My problem now is How can I use this different collection which has category name,id and index to sort the products collection by category index?

Comment: can you attach the data of the categoryData?

Comment: @MunsifAli last snippet of code/json is the category data.

Comment: do you want to sort the the last snippet data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to sort the last snippet data you can use sort method like this

```
   myList.sort((a, b) => int.parse(a["index"].toString())
    .compareTo(int.parse(b["index"].toString())));
```

checkout the full code here https://dartpad.dev/?id=252d17ac9c3f254da2955bb90da83d29

Answer (score 1):

To sort the "products" collection by the category index, you can make a separate query to the "category" collection to get the category index and then use that index to sort the "products" collection. You can use the following code to get the sorted "products" data:

```
List<Map<String, dynamic>> sortedProductData = [];
for (var doc in categoryData!) {
  Map<String, dynamic> data = doc as Map<String, dynamic>;
  for (var product in productItemsData!) {
    Map<String, dynamic> productData = product as Map<String, dynamic>;
    if (productData["category"] == data["categoryName"]) {
      sortedProductData.insert(data["index"], productData);
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Note: `categoryData` is the data obtained from the "category" collection and `productItemsData` is the data obtained from the "products" collection.

Comment: For this method I get the follwong error at "sortedProductData.insert(" point.                                  Invalid value: Not in inclusive range 0..5: 7

Comment: @SameeraTennakoon create a sortedProductData list of required size with value of nulls like ``sortedProductData = List.filled(collection.size, null)`` then insert into list.